# How to get valid file name and extension from remote url to save it.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I want to get actual file extension from the remote url.

sometimes extension not in valid format.

for example 
 I getting problem from below URLs

```
1) http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/media-upload.png?w=266
2) http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/a5a5ed70fa7c651aa5ec9ca8de57a4b8?s=60&d=identicon&r=G
```

I want to download/save remote image from remote url..

How to get filename and extension from the above url?

Thanks 
Abhishek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The remote server sends a `Content-Type` header containing the mime type of the resource. For example:

```
Content-Type: image/png
```

So you can examine the value of this header and pick the proper extension for your file. For example:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/a5a5ed70fa7c651aa5ec9ca8de57a4b8?s=60&d=identicon&r=G");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    string contentType = response.ContentType;
    // TODO: examine the content type and decide how to name your file
    string filename = "test.jpg";

    // Download the file
    using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(filename))
    {
        // Remark: if the file is very big read it in chunks
        // to avoid loading it into memory
        byte[] buffer = new byte[response.ContentLength];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: How we get Content-Type when we send web request.?

Comment: You can't. After all, how can you anticipate what a server will send you until it actually has sent it? Once you have the WebResponse, you can get its content-type.

Comment: @Abhishek Bhalani, the Content-Type header is on the response, not on the request. I have shown an example.

Comment: @Darin Thanks, But How can I want to download file after webrequest.?

Comment: @Abhishek Bhalani, of course that you can. The file is inside the response Stream. Simply read this stream. I have updated my answer to illustrate with an example.

Comment: Hello @Darin when i trying to write file then it not opened.. size of every file is 37kb only... What that issue.?

Comment: @Abhishek Bhalani, are you changing the request url? What do you mean by `file not opened`? It worked when I tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) if you want to extract the extension from a URL.

```
var ext = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(pathstring)
```

Or use headers to determine the content type. There's a Windows API to convert content type to extension (it's also in registry), but for web apps it makes sense to use mapping.

```
switch(response.ContentType)
{
    case "image/jpeg":
        return ".jpeg";
    case "image/png":
        return ".png";
}
```

Comment: I tried with URL: "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/a5a5ed70fa7c651aa5ec9ca8de57a4b8?s=60&d=identicon&r=G"  then it throw exception..

Comment: Yeah it uses the string in the same way as `Path` for file system paths. If it doesn't have an extension it won't work you'll need the content-type approach.